# How to pass path params using command in REFIT .NET

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, parameters, refit

This is my refit interface

```
public interface IRefitInterface
{

    [Get("/v1/report/student-statement")]
    Task<GetStudentRecordResponse> GetStudentsRecordsAsync(
        GetStudentRecordCommand command,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}
```

This is how my command looks like :

```
public sealed class GetStudentRecordCommand
{
    public GetStudentRecordCommand(string id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
    [AliasAs("id")]
    public string Id { get; private set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

I want to send this id in path parameters like this :

```
[Get("/v1/report/student-statement/{id}")]
```

But I don't want to add it in command parameters due to some constraint's, I want to handle it in command.

I achieved similar thing for query params like this :

```
public sealed class GetStudentRecordCommand
{
    public GetStudentRecordCommand(string id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
    
    [Query]
    [AliasAs("id")]
    public string Id { get; private set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

But unable to achieve it for path params ?

How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

This one worked :

```
[Get("/v1/report/student-statement/{command.Id}")]
```